# Missing "Debug" button for crashed application (window "<process> has stopped working")

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, debug, windows-10-v1709

After the last major **Windows update** (from (I think) 1703 to 1709), the "Debug" button **disappeared** from the pop-up for crashed applications.

The automatic debugging seems to be enabled (in the registry).
The just-in-time debugging is also enabled in my Visual Studio 2015 (there was a warning there, that another debugger was registered, but I "repaired" (via the installator) the VS and the warning is now gone).

Any other ideas?

The `<process> has stopped working` pop-up now has only one button - `Close program`.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me, but I still don't find a perfect solution. A available solution maybe set the Auto = 1 for these two registry:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug and 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug.
Then if the application crash, the JIT will automatically setup.